# Trivia game database

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, storage

In my trivia game (for Windows Phone 7) I will have a list of questions in which there are 4 possible answers and only one of them is correct, and the category in which the question belong... So I decided to make one database which will have **idQuestion, Category, Question, WrongAns1, WrongAns2, WrongAns3, CorrectAns** and this will be stored in local database... but I also want to have another database in my server where I will put new questions and when user press update questions it will retrieve all questions from there and save them in his local database so he could play offline... Which is best way to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to store your questions in two different places?

Comment: Take a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx)

Comment: @Jodrell one local and one in my server where I put new questions and each time user press update questions its passing the new questions to his local database

Comment: @Oliver so in few words while user is offline it uses the questions that are cached and when he goes online its downloading automatically the changes?

Comment: @Loclip: In short: Yes. You should take a look into the [Database Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx) and their especially into the [Executing Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928606.aspx) description. Just take it as a start step and check if it fits your needs.

Comment: Write it as answer and I will give you best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Answer from Oliver (Read Comments)

Take a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to add a time column.

When the user updates the questions, the update will consider only server questions which are newer than the latest local question.

Comment: This is not my question... my question is how to send questions from server database to local database... what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Given a simple schema like that, it should be easy enough to write the data to a file in a JSON or XML-like format and save it into isolated storage locally.

What you probably will need to do however, is store all of the answers (both wrong and right) as hashes instead of plain-text, and update your application logic accordingly to compare the stored hashes with in-flight hashes of the answers provided by the user (thereby preventing any attempts by unscrupulous users to cheat by discerning the answers from the local storage).

Whenever the user selects the 'update questions' function, it's just a matter of running a comparison of the question Id's from isolated storage against the question Id's in the on-line database and saving to isolated storage any new questions from the on-line database.

Comment: Why its better to use json or xml? So when user press update questions button it will download the json or xml file and replace it with old?